# Xamarin Mac application doesn't react when I try to allow it in Dropbox

Tags: macos, webview, dropbox, xamarin.mac

I am developing a Xamarin Mac application and I need to do some data syncing with Dropbox.

I have created a WebView which navigates to a URL where the user is prompted to enter its username and password. After hitting OK and successfully signing in I am presented with a new screen where I can grant or deny the app access to it's folder in Apps > AppName inside Dropbox.

Regardless of hitting Cancel or Allow nothing happens. If I however click on the Dropbox icon on the top left I am navigated normally to my dashboard.

I thought that this might be a Javascript problem or something similar but I have changed all the properties I can think of and I am still stuck on the same page.

What I need to set to be able to move on?

Comment: I also suspect a JavaScript error. Can you check the JavaScript console in that browser to see if/what that may be? Also, in any case, what browser doe the WebView use? If it isn't officially support ( https://www.dropbox.com/help/3 ) I would recommend jumping out to the normal system browser instead.

Comment: I have put the task aside since I had to do some other stuff but I am now back at this and didn't get any further. Can you explain what you mean by " I would recommend jumping out to the normal system browser instead". How can I catch the interaction between the system browser and dropbox from outside my app.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202340919-Cocoa-WebView-not-reacting-to-Allow-button-click- ]

Comment: I meant that I would recommend sending the user to visit the /authorize URL in their own browser (e.g., Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, etc.). That way, the user is more likely to use a supported browser (per https://www.dropbox.com/help/3 ). Once the user authorizes your app, you can use an OAuth callback to notify/get back to your app. That's that `oauth_callback` parameter in OAuth 1, or the `redirect_uri` parameter in OAuth 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution for my problem which is quite a strange one (IMO) but maybe it's the default way on OSX.

I subscribed to all event's the webView control has to offer and I found this "nugget".

Once the user clicked on "Allow" the `CancelClientRedirect` event was raised and by chance I found out that if you check out the

```
YourWebViewControl.MainFrameUrl
```

you could see which callback URL should have been called.

It would either be `http://yoururl.com/oauth=someRandomString` or `http://yoururl.com/not_approved=true`.

Based on this URL you can then know what happened (i.e. app (not) authorized) and then do whatever you want in response to that.

Hope this might help someone out!